# What is wrong with my rock, paper, scissors code?

Tags: python, random

Using python, I have to create a rock paper scissors game for school that the user plays against the computer. The computer's choice also has to be random. When i try to run this code its says that there is a syntax error but not where it is. Can anyone help?

```
    import random

print("Welcome to rock paper scissors.")

player = False

while player == False:
    print(" ")
    print("Press 1 for Rock")
    print("Press 2 for Paper")
    print("Press 3 for Scissors")

    User = int(input("Rock, Paper or Scissors?"))
    Com = random.randrange(1,3)

    if (User == 1) and (Com == 1):
        player = False
    print("Its a draw!")

    elif (User == 2) and (Com == 1):
        player = True
    print("You win!")

    elif (User == 3) and (Com == 1):
        player = True
    print("You lose!")

    elif (User == 1) and (Com == 2):
        player = True
    print("You lose!")

    elif (User == 2) and (Com == 2):
        player = False
    print("Its a draw!")

    elif (User == 3) and (Com == 2):
        player = True
    print("You win!")

    elif (User == 1) and (Com == 3):
        player = True
    print("You win!")

    elif (User == 2) and (Com == 3):
        player = True
    print("You lose!")

    elif (User == 3) and (Com == 3):
        player = False
    print("Its a draw! You both entered scissors.")

    else:
        print("Make sure to enter a number from 1 - 3")
```

Comment: I believe the syntax issue that your `print` commands are not indented into the conditionals. You can't have a print command (outside of the indent) and continue on to an `elif`. All commands for a single case should have the same indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @jedruniu said, you have incorrect indentation. I additionally took the liberty of cleaning up your code so it's less confusing:

```
import random

print("Welcome to rock paper scissors.")

draw = True

while draw:
    print()
    print("Press 1 for Rock")
    print("Press 2 for Paper")
    print("Press 3 for Scissors")
    User = int(input("Rock, Paper or Scissors?"))
    Com = random.randint(1,3)

    if User == Com:
        print("Its a draw!")

    else:
        draw = False #so it doesn't repeat

        if (User == 2) and (Com == 1):
            print("You win!")

        elif (User == 3) and (Com == 1):
            print("You lose!")

        elif (User == 1) and (Com == 2):
            print("You lose!")

        elif (User == 3) and (Com == 2):
            print("You win!")

        elif (User == 1) and (Com == 3):
            print("You win!")

        elif (User == 2) and (Com == 3):
            print("You lose!")

        else:
            print("Make sure to enter a number from 1 - 3")
```

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

```
if (User == 1) and (Com == 1):
    player = False
print("Its a draw!")

elif (User == 2) and (Com == 1):
    player = True
print("You win!")
```

Your print statement with `print("Its a draw!")` does not belong to the `if`. You can't have anything 'loose' between `if` and `elif`.

Also your import is indented, but I believe this is formatting error.

It repairs your error but be aware that your naming conventions aren't saying much about the code.